# How to run functions one after the other after one function has fully executed when functions are both synchronous and asynchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I am new to react and am trying to run functions one after the other.

This is my code:

```
submit = () => {
    this.props.toggle();
    this.props.getValue(); 
    this.notify();
    this.props.resetValidation();
    this.props.disable();
    this.props.actionCost();
};
```

Here getValue is an asynchronous function and notify is a react toastify function, rest are synchronous function. I want to run getValue first and then run all the other functions after it has been executed. How do I do that. Presently all functions are running simultaneously

Please help

Comment: If `getValue()` is asynchronous, it would either accept a function as a callback that fires once it is complete or would return a Promise that resolves/rejects once the async operation is finished (if this is the case, you. can use `.then()` or `await` on the Promise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `getValue` is an `async` function, it returns a Promise object, and you want other functions to be executed after `getValue` has completed it's execution, you can either use `.then()` or `await` on `getValue`. 
Using `.then()`.

```
 submit = () => {
    
    this.props.getValue().then(res=>{
      this.props.toggle();  //All these functions execute only after getValue has completed it's execution.
      this.notify();
      this.props.resetValidation();
      this.props.disable();
      this.props.actionCost();
    })
};
```

Using **await**

```
submit = async() => {
    await this.props.getValue();  //Note that this should be placed on top as this is the function you want to run first, and other functions to execute only after this has completed.
    this.props.toggle();
    this.notify();
    this.props.resetValidation();
    this.props.disable();
    this.props.actionCost();
};
```

Since your `getValues` function uses an axios function, you should return the promise after axios has completed its operation. Your `getValues` should be something like this:
Making `getValues` an `async` function

```
const getValues = async() =>{
  let res = await axios.get('URL') //Just an instance, change the axios method(GET,POST,PUT) according to your needs.

  return res
}
```

(OR)
Return a promise from `getValues`.

```
const getValues = () =>{
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      axios.get('URL',response=>{
          resolve("AXIOS REQUEST COMPLETE")
      }
 })
}
```

You can update your `getValues` to any of the above-described ways, and call  `getValues` as shown earlier and it shall work as expected.

Comment: I am getting this in the first method:TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
SubmitConfirmation._this.submit [as onClick]
D:/UdemyProjects/special-request/special-request/src/views/pages/SubmitConfirmation.js:40
  37 | 
  38 |  submit = () => {
  39 |    this.props.toggle();
> 40 |    this.props.getValue().then(res => {

Comment: in the second method the functions are still implemented first??

Comment: in the first method I am getting  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Comment: What action are you performing in `getValue`? Is it something to do with networking calls or something time-consuming? And is `getValue` defined to be `async`, i.e, `getValue = async()=>{...}` ?

Comment: GetValue is an axios call to a web api

Comment: it is not defined as async explicitly however axios calls are async functions

Comment: The wrapper function should return a Promise object (either by `return new Promise`) or should be defined as `async` that'd wrap the return result in a Promise. That's the reason why `.then` came to be undefined, and also why all the functions are running first without actually obeying the `Promises` rules.

Comment: Although axios calls are async functions, here, their scope is localized and not chained to the parent function, i.e, the parent function is not returning the promise object returned by `axios` itself.

Comment: so how do I rectify it?

Comment: Hi Prajwal I tried the then method it is now working once I made getvalue async however the other functions are still running first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238505/discussion-between-prajwal-kulkarni-and-sambit).

Comment: I've updated the answer, kindly check.

Answer (score 3):

```
 submit = async () => {
    this.props.toggle();
    await this.props.getValue(); 
    this.notify();
    this.props.resetValidation();
    this.props.disable();
    this.props.actionCost();
};
```

Comment: Hi just wondering should it be async submit = () => {}; or submit = async () => {} as it is giving an error in my editor

Comment: Also I tried async and its still the same

Answer (score 0):

You should define the submit method as an async method and it will be like this:

```
submit = async () => {
    this.props.toggle();
    await this.props.getValue(); 
    this.notify();
    this.props.resetValidation();
    this.props.disable();
    this.props.actionCost();
};
```